# shell script help - checking for file exists

Tags: unix

I'm not sure why this code isn't working. Its not going to the copy command. 
I successfully run this manually on the command line (without the check)
I don't think i'm performing a correct file check? Is there a better, cleaner way to write this?
I just want to make sure the file exists, if so, copy it over.  Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: getcnf.sh <remote-host>" 2>&1
    exit 1
fi

#Declare variables
HOURDATE=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M'`
STAMP=`date '+%Y%m%d-%H:%M'`
REMOTE_MYCNF=/var/log/mysoft/mysoft.log
BACKUP_DIR=/home/mysql/dev/logs/
export REMOTE_MYCNF HOURDATE STAMP

#Copy file over
echo "Checking for mysoft.log file $REMOTE_MYCNF $STAMP" 2>&1
if [ -f $REMOTE_MYCNF ]; then
echo "File exists lets bring a copy over...." 2>&1
   /usr/bin/scp $1:$REMOTE_MYCNF $BACKUP_DIR$1.mysoft.log
echo "END CP" 2>&1
   exit 0
   else
        echo "Unable to get file" 2>&1
        exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your checking existing file on remote computer seems like:
you should do:

```
ssh $host "test -f $file"
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it to work this way. Why doesn't like it if its written like this? Is it the spacing?  `if [$? =0]; then`

Answer (score 2):

use sh -x script.sh to see what is happening.

Comment: thanks, its going "Unable to get file", so its not even hitting the scp. This works if I remove the entire if statement all together. So does that mean, my if statement is not constructed correctly??

Comment: It should show the if statement with the variables substituted, check that it is ok and head the file it shows.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for the existence of a remote file

```
$1:$REMOTE_MYCNF
```

using the local name `$REMOTE_MYCNF`. The `if` test is never satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check that `$1` is set.

Your file check runs on the local machine - not on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if to:

```
if[! -f $REMOTE_MYCNF -o ! -d $REMOTE_MYCNF];
```

Comment: this will work but is not correct, see aaa's answer. Also, -e checks for files and dirs so no need for this or.